# data input from excel to html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to copy data from excel (cell by cell) and paste it into the fields of an HTML page and click on some buttons on the HTML page in order to do some processing. What will be the best technology to write a script for doing this task repetitively and also a bit of error handling if any record runs into error?

Answer (score 0):

the workflow I've for a similar situation was to copy the whole column from excel and paste into a `textarea`- each row is represented as a new line when you copy and paste a whole row from excel, then you can use jQuery to find all the data using `$('textarea').val().split("\n")`